# Update data to Upper Case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table where 5 column is there with Data. How to update data of 3 String columns to uppercase?

Comment: Hint:  `update`, `upper()`.

Comment: update tableName set col1 = upper(col1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = UPPER(your_column)
```